# Android - How can I create a hexagon in Android and rotate it with animation?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-animation, shapes

I know basic level Android, but haven't had done animation before. Moreover, I don't have any clue as to how can I create custom Geometrical objects like triangle, Hexagon, etc.

Moreover, I don't know anything about doing animation in Android. I'd like to have relevant tutorial links or blogs which can help understand the basics and preferable a sample code for "Rotation" animation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/nehe-android/ (the code is best documentation ^_^)
but it is for open gl custom objects on top of your view/surface view, it is commonly used in games.

If you want to do just rotation for Button, there are http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html and subclasses of it (RotateAnimation  and so on), you can even do a custom one. By this way you can do awesome user experience for application which use default android controls.

Cheers